# MySQL counter variable groupby

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which displays userid,grade and examid. I need a variable which would give me concatenation of userid,usrgrade and increment examid. I tried the below mentioned query and it is not working. can some body help me please

```
select sub.*,CONCAT(UserId, '-',Grade,'-', rank) as CounterVariable  from (
    SELECT @rn:=CASE WHEN (@usr = us.userid and @us @usrex<>us.userexamid) THEN @rn ELSE @rn+1 END AS rank,
               @usr:=us.userid as usr,
              @usrex:=us.userexamid as usrex,
              @usrgrade: @us.grade as usrgrade
    us.userid                                                AS UserId,
    e.level                                                   AS level,
    us.grade                                                  AS Grade,   
    us.userexamid as UserExam,
    from
    usersections us
    cross join (SELECT @rn:=0) t1
    cross join (SELECT @usr=0) t2
    cross join (SELECT @usrex=0) t3
    cross join (SELECT @usrgrade=0) t4
    GROUP BY
    us.userid,
    us.grade,
    us.userexamid)sub
```

### UserID UserGrade UserExamId counter

1        2        3       1-2-0

1        2        4       1-2-1

1        3        5       1-3-0

1        3        6       1-3-1

2        2        7       2-2-0

2        3        8       2-3-0

Comment: Can somebody help me on this please ?

Comment: @sameermirji - Can you help please ?